# Using javascript, how to measure image surfaces in crop-like fashion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-plugins

I want to build a crop-like tool that can basically select an area of an image using mouse and give back its surface? 
What do you suggest, is there any plugin that can help me; I dont want to start from scratch.

Comment: If you're just looking for an existing plugin, then it's off-topic.

Comment: I don't know whether there is a plugin. So why the downvotes.

Comment: No, I'm not joking. If you're just here to search for a list of existing plugins, you're not at the right place. See faq. So I supposed you wanted to know how it can be done.

Comment: @Honesta You asked about the downvotes: just google "jquery select image area" and the first result will be the [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) plugin for jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [**imgAreaSelect**](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)

It's a plugin for jQuery.